# NODE.JS App gets stuck getting 2.5 million of records through and api

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, profiling, cpu

I've got the code that retrieves couple of millions of rows from a db and a couple of millions through an api.

```
            let closedOrdersStartDate;
            preparedOrdersPromise = tickApiConnector.obtainToken().then(function () {
                return ordersController.getAllTrades(0, [], 0, accountIdsToRun);
            }).then(function (trades) {
                closedOrdersStartDate = new Date();
                return Promise.all([trades, fthsApiConnector.getData('closed_orders', '&sort=id', 10000, 0)]);
            }).then(function (tradesAndClosedOrderIds) {
                //stuck before getting there
                console.log('now processing orders time spent from starting getting closed_orders till now is: ' +
                  ((new Date().getTime() - closedOrdersStartDate.getTime())/ 1000) + ' seconds');
                return ordersController.processOrders(tradesAndClosedOrderIds[0], tradesAndClosedOrderIds[1]);
            });
```

The app gets stuck after calling that `getData()` function.

```
getData: async function (entityName, getParams = '', perRequest = 10000, skip = 0) {
  if(getParams.indexOf('&take=') !== -1) {
    return fthsApiRequest(entityName, getParams);
  }

  const totalCount = await fthsApiRequest(entityName, getParams + '&getCount');

  let result = [];
  let count = 0;
  while(count < totalCount) {
    result = result.concat(await fthsApiRequest(entityName, getParams + '&take=' + perRequest + '&skip=' + count));
    count += perRequest;
  }

  return result;
}
```

The function executes till the last request(I see it in logs) and after that the script gets unresponsable. I thought that it could be a memory leak and I've rewritten that **getData()** function in different ways but still, there's enough memory on the server and the script doesn't consume even a bit of it. Still I get  100% of CPU load in a while after that last iteration of **getData()** is rant. After that the app gets stuck forever.

I've tried profiling it. And there are thousands of **Code move event for unknown code: 0x2a5c24bfb4c0**, I'm not sure what that means, but there could be a clue in that. Here's the [V8.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17clGDQGfBzuqaoqjncD8lSYb6JCdAoXR/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

The possible problem maybe in block :

```
while(count < totalCount) { result = result.concat(await fthsApiRequest(entityName, getParams + '&take=' + perRequest + '&skip=' + count)); count += perRequest; }
```

Ensure that the api give response. And on the last statement :

```
return result;
```

In async function the better use :

```
return Promise.resolve(result);
```

Comment: Api gives the response. As I've told all the data is loaded but after it's loaded it gets stuck. As to return Promise.resolve(result); I'll try it, but why do you think it should help?